# Repeat elements in nested list with n in another nested list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a nested list of something that I would like to transform by repeating each element a given number of times specified in another nested list (of identical structure).

Example:

```
phrases = [ ['Happy birthday to you','Happy birthday dear Einstein'],
            ['Happy birthday to you']
          ]

reps = [ [2, 1],
         [1]
       ]

#------- Desired output looks like:           -------------------------------------------
out = [ ['Happy birthday to you','Happy birthday to you','Happy birthday dear Einstein'],
        ['Happy birthday to you']
      ]
```

Using a nested loop via a list comprehension, I have tried:

```
[ [phrases[i][j] for rep in range(reps[i][j])] 
   for i in range(len(phrases)) 
     for j in range(len(phrases[i])) ]
#Returns:
#[['Happy birthday to you', 'Happy birthday to you'],
# ['Happy birthday dear Einstein'],
# ['Happy birthday to you']]
```

Which is not quite what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) combined with `zip` for this:

```
import numpy as np

res = [np.repeat(i, j).tolist() for i, j in zip(phrases, reps)]

# [['Happy birthday to you',
#   'Happy birthday to you',
#   'Happy birthday dear Einstein'],
#  ['Happy birthday to you']]
```

Comment: For me, the simplicity of this approach compared to the pure base list comprehension outweighs the additional dependency.  Thanks to you and @Ajax1234 for your answers.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `zip`:

```
phrases = [ ['Happy birthday to you','Happy birthday dear Einstein'],
        ['Happy birthday to you']
      ]

reps = [ [2, 1],
     [1]
   ]

new_data = [[i for b in [[c]*d for c, d in zip(a, b)] for i in b] for a, b in zip(phrases, reps)]
```

Output:

```
[
['Happy birthday to you', 'Happy birthday to you', 'Happy birthday dear Einstein'], 
['Happy birthday to you']
]
```